# Angular 4 trigger event for dynamic checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop

i have created a div element and dynamic checkbox along with change function. But on click of the checkbox, the function is not called

My Code

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Dropdown',
    template: `<div class="select">
        <div class="selectBox" (change)="Checkboxes()">
          <select multiple>
            <option id='Option' (click)='Click()'>Select an option</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="checkboxesdiv">
      </div></div>`
})
```

In *ngOnInit* I have declared the string with dynamic values and assigned to the innerHtml of the template

```
    let option = "";
    for(let item of DBdata){
    option += "<label for='" + item.id+ "' title='" + item.des+ "'><input class='Optioninputclass' (change)='ChangeFn()' type='checkbox' id = '" + item.id+ "'/>" + item.des+ "</label>"
    }

    var select = document.getElementById("checkboxesdiv");
    select.innerHTML = this.optionValue;
```

the **ChangeFn** not called on clicking of the checkbox. I have tried `(click)='ChangeFn()'` also, but same result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `ChangeFn`? where is your `Checkboxes()` function? what do you expect the `(change)` bit to do?

Comment: DOM manipulation is exactly the thing Angular discourages. More importantly, if you have to play around with the DOM, say jQuery for instance, the ngAfterViewInit is the event.

Comment: Checkboxes() will assign style display block to the label element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular templates are compiled during the build. When you set the content dynamically via innerHTML, you cannot use angular syntax (or you can, but it is simply ignored). What you should do instead is create the checkoxes in your template using *ngFor.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Dropdown',
    template: `<div class="select">
        <div class="selectBox" (change)="Checkboxes()">
        <select multiple>
            <option id='Option' (click)='Click()'>Select an option</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="checkboxesdiv">
            <label [for]="item.id" [title]="item.des" *ngFor="let item of DBdata">
                <input class="Optioninputclass" (change)="ChangeFn()" type="checkbox" [id]="item.id"/>{{ item.des }} 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>`
})
```

Just make sure that DBdata is a public field in your component, so the template can access it.

Comment: DBData doesnt need to be public, private variables/arrays/objects work too

Comment: They do not work if you compile with AOT. Everything you access in your template needs to be public in that case.

Comment: not true, they only need to be public if you want other classes/components to read the value. private indicates that only that component, and corresponding html files, can access it

Comment: Here some is some further reading on that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387145/why-angular-component-field-should-be-public?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You got that wrong. Please read the link I provided. When you build with AOT (which angular does when you build in prod mode), template are compiled into classes, hence the field needs to be public in order the be accessible by the template.

Comment: as of angular 4 (4.1.3 and 4.3.4), i have not got that wrong

Comment: Can you provide a link for that? Here are the offical angular docs which state exactly what I said: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler . Have a look at the section "Phase 2: code generation"

Comment: i cant exactly provide a link to working angular projects when they are private to the company

Comment: I just tested this with angular cli and angular 5. Create a new project using angular cli with ```ng new AOT-TEST```, then go to app.component.ts and make the title field private. Now run an aot build with ```ng build --aot```. This will result in an error. I invite you to test it yourself before you give out wrong advice. Maybe I need to point out, that you don't need to explicitly add the public modifier, as every field without modifier is public by default. As I said, the aot build will fail if your field is not public.

Comment: i never said angular 5, i said angular 4, naming 4.1.3 and 4.3.4